# Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I noticed that some posts I definitely already reviewed at some point show up again.

It is impossible for me to suppress these; clicking "review answer/question" increments the review count, but the post still shows up when I reload (and the review count correctly resets, which shows that at some level the system knows these posts are already reviewed).

In case a dev wants to have a look at the database, [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/is-the-movement-and-ghost-ai-in-the-super-nintendo-ms-pac-man-faithful-to-the-a/21613#21613) is one of the posts that keep showing up in the low quality posts tab, no matter how many times I review it.

I do have 1k reputation and the Strunk & White badge, by the way.

Comment: is this still the case ?

Comment: @waffles Yes. .

Comment: I am also having this issue as of yesterday. It was working fine before. Specifically, I'm looking at the Month filter of the Late Answers section. If I review an answer, the review count increments, but if I refresh the page or leave and come back, the post reappears and my count drops again. This has been happening with several posts, not just the same one every time.

Comment: This is still the case. Another question on this issue was closed but this is still happening as of right now.

Comment: @BenBrocka Did you by any chance start reviewing right away when the feature was unveiled? Because those posts that won't disappear are mostly older ones I reviewed the day it was introduced. Might just be a coincidence, though.

Comment: This has been happening for a few weeks now, if you disable random sorting in review and select "all", clicking page 1 again after reviewing the entire 50 posts will give you the same 50 posts and they are reviewable again.  I figured this was because a posts needs a certain total number of unique reviews before clearing the low quality list?

Comment: it is still happening to me. It happens only to some post not to others. I was opening a bug/question about the problem on meta and I got to this question. There is someone being aware of these comments and taking some action ? I mean, there is not any answer here...There is something I could do ?. This behavior is very upsetting. You are visiting the same posts again and again and again...

Comment: Same here. I thought we could get the number of remaining posts to review down to 0 in no time.

Comment: Same issue here on Programmers.SE. I'm stuck with 40 late answers for the "year" panel, and the "all" panel, and they don't disapear, whatever I do to them.

Comment: Has been reported on [su] [as well](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3886/4377)  @waffles

Comment: For example [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/what-kanban-specific-software-is-out-there/123362#123362) doesn't disappear from my review list (late answers / month).

Comment: This is _still_ still the case for me too.

Comment: Retains the same 48 questions on http://superuser.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=month

Comment: @waffles: I provided a video in [my similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116048/review-panel-isnt-marking-that-ive-reviewed-posts).

Comment: I actually had a _dream_ about this bug being fixed. Read into that what you will. :)

Comment: This bug happening on the Graphic Design beta as well.  Affects all categories on Month filter.

Comment: @waffles This is still happening to me on Gaming.  [Here's one.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/how-can-i-get-out-of-the-lava-without-dying/28772#28772)

Comment: @waffles [Another unreviewable post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/why-did-my-zombie-pigmen-form-a-flash-mob/31028#31028).

Comment: @waffles Occurring on SO today.  Doesn't happen for day/week/month but does happen for all and year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happened cause my implementation was a bit naive.

When removing posts from the global list:

1. I removed all posts that were reviewed by 2 reviewers
2. I removed all posts you reviewed in the last 7 days.

I assumed that someone else will review all the posts you reviewed in that 7 day window.

Clearly I was wrong.

Comment: Yes, when going through the thousand-post-deep review backlog with random ordering, that's not a likely event. As far as I can tell, this is fixed.

Comment: Yay!  Reviewing is fun again!

Comment: I always wondered why edited posts appeared in review, from reading this I take it that it needs two of edits/upvotes/flags/closevotes to disappear?