# Reviewed items not disappearing from /review

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again)

Yesterday, I reviewed every remaining post on my [`[wicket]` late answers `/review` page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=all&tag=wicket), as well as some posts from other `/review` pages. Today, I'm still seeing some of those posts on assorted `/review` pages.

For example, I edited and upvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907163/122607) from "Wicket first answer review" yesterday, and I'm still seeing it there now. The upvote and the edit from earlier are still there. Similar story for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415118/jsf-2-0-vs-apache-wicket/7631958#7631958) from "Wicket late answer review."

I also don't think the page gave me credit for any of the [wicket](/questions/tagged/wicket) reviews, although I don't know for sure how many reviews I performed yesterday.