# Review feature not removing posts when you review them

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again)

I've been reviewing lots of posts on UX.SE and I noticed I swear I've seen some of these posts before. Well some posts in review *never ever go away* for me, and I'm thinking it's because I'm the only one that's reviewed them.

[Here's a Screenr screen recording of the problem](http://www.screenr.com/5Dbs). Those 13 posts have been in the Closed tab of my review for nearly a month. As you can see my review count goes up when I "rereview" them on the current page, but the counter resets once I refresh the page, because I already reviewed those--why do they show up?

Other posts I've reviewed disapear from review, in fact most of them do go away. But this makes reviewing extremely frustrating as I'll often go to review, I go over a whole page of 10 items and more than half of them I've already reviewed. That's not helping me help the site and it's frustrating me so much I've stopped reviewing.

Comment: If I'm right in assuming the posts are not disappearing because I'm the only one that's reviewed them, this effect will be most noticeable on small/beta sites, Stackoverflow users will probably never notice it.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour for tex.sx.

Comment: Who says SO users will never notice it? I've reviewed every single post in one of the smaller tags on SO, and that's where [I noticed it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114042/reviewed-items-not-disappearing-from-review). My report was closed -- correctly -- as a dupe of [this even earlier one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again), though. (Which I now notice you've commented on, so I'm not sure why you're asking again.)

Comment: I noticed the same behavior when the selected tab is "all" or "year"; I thought it was by design, as I don't notice it when the tab is not one of those two.

Comment: @PopularDemand I found several related questions a while ago looking for answers, none had any action taken and most weren't quite the same issue. I do note that it's over a month later with no response save "me too" issue reports...