# Review panel isn't marking that I've reviewed posts?

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again)

All of a sudden, the review panel has stopped marking posts that I review as reviewed. When I click on "review the answer" in the late answers tab, it opens the answer and increments my total number of posts reviewed over at the right. However, if I then click the late answers tab again, the post still appears there and my total at the right has been decremented back to the number it was before.

It only appears to be doing this for a *majority* of the posts that are reviewable. Some posts will review perfectly fine and stay hidden, but it seems like it's become a 1 in 25 shot now...

**Edit:** For those of you who might call out the "link or it didn't happen" I made [an entire video](http://youtu.be/V95epMYE9eE). Enjoy. :)

Comment: @Popular: Good find. I'm going to leave this here rather than deleting and posting there, as a good alternate rewording of the same question. :) I've voted to close though.

Comment: I only had it handy because my own recent post about this behavior was closed as a dupe of it. I wasn't going to vote to close until after I watched your video -- I'm still at work at the moment -- but I suspect this'll be closed by the time I get home.