# Don't show questions in Review and Tools that I already cast close votes on

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Please don't make us click through all the questions in *Review → Close* and *Tools → Close* just to know if we already voted on them or not.

This isn't a duplicate of [Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again) - all questions are removed from the list once I open them (which isn't good either, [but that's a different issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117949/dont-remove-questions-from-review-close-after-just-opening-them)). The problem is, that I am shown questions that I already voted on in the first place.

Comment: Please don't remove the automatically inserted text. It makes it difficult to manage the questions

Comment: Can you focus your question a bit? Are you just asking to not see questions in review if you already cast a close vote on them while using the site outside the Review page? I tried to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @AnnaLear That's the right direction, yeah. I don't expect questions to appear in some kind of todo list, when there's nothing to do for me. Therefore I expect the same behavior for close votes as for moderation flags (no entries for stuff I flagged, entries disappear once I took action).