# Don't remove questions from 'Review → Close' after just opening them

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Whenever I click on a question in /review/close, it is gone the next time I open the site, even if I didn't vote to close it. As a consequence, I now have ~200 supposedly reviewed questions and there seems to be no way to make them re-appear in /review/close.

Hovering the *Hiding reviewed and closed posts* text in the *Your Review Stats* box on the right side shows:

> A post is considered reviewed as soon as you or 2 other users click the review button

That sounds like a good idea to solve this issue, but I haven't found that button anywhere. *confused*

Comment: \*confused\* at this question... why did you open 200 questions and didn't vote/edit/close/flag ?

Comment: That's not the point. Opening a question isn't the same as reviewing it. E.g., I open a question, don't yet know what to do with it, close the browser, try to find it one hour later without success, because it has already been removed from my review list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `review answer` or `review question` at the bottom of a post *is* the review button.  If you've clicked it, the post disappears from your review queue.

If you're the second person to have clicked review on a particular item, it drops out of everyone's Review queue.

I understand wanting to preview the post before committing to review it, but I think a temporary fix to leave it in the queue is to right click the title (before you click `review answer`) and open the question in another tab/window to get the whole picture.

Comment: Ah, that's supposed to be a button. !:-) Yeah, the workaround is what I'm looking for. Though I'd prefer the question link to just lead to the question and the review link/button to also remove it from the list. Guess I'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 8):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Reviewing a post is meant to attain immediate action. It's not click the review button, ponder on the decision for a day or so, then come back and complete some action. By not taking any action on it, you have *reviewed* the post and determined that no action needed to be taken by you. That's the point of reviewing. I have reviewed over 20,000 posts, but I've only taken action on around 1,500 of those.

So synopsis:

- Open the review panel.
- Click the "review question/answer" link, which will show the full post. At this point, **the post is now marked as having been reviewed by you**. Whether or not you take any action after clicking that link makes no difference.
- Decide whether or not to take action. If you do, cool, you're helping. Otherwise it is implied that no action needed to be taken (case closed).

Unless you run into the annoying bug where posts re-appear after being reviewed, there is no possible way to make previously reviewed posts re-appear manually, and there really shouldn't be any need to do that either.

Comment: I don't see how this is by design. The site states "A post is considered reviewed as soon as you or 2 other users click the review button" - I clicked on the question link, not the review button/link, yet the question disappeared. Also, no question disappears from any of the *Tools* sections unless I review them.